# How to extract particular value from xml file and modify it using perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

Here is the xml code where I want to extract 'string' value macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver and modify it as NoDatabase using perl.

File name- neo-datasource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<wddxPacket version="1.0">
   <header/>
     -<data>
        -<array length="2">
          -<struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
             -<var name="CFASTSTJ">
                -<struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
                   -<var name="alter">
                      <boolean value="true"/>
                    </var>
                   -<var name="CLASS">
                       <string>macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver</string>
                    </var>
                 </struct>
           </struct>
         </array>
       </data>      
</wddxpacket>
```

Please anyone can share your ideas or perl script.

Comment: Could you share the perl code you've tried so far?

Comment: That is not well-formed XML. Please fix it

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough using an XML Parser. Like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig).

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'var[@name="CLASS"]/string' => sub { $_->set_text('NoDatabase') }
    }
)->parse( \*DATA )->print;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
   <header/>
     <data>
        <array length="2">
          <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
             <var name="CFASTSTJ">
                <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
                   <var name="alter">
                      <boolean value="true"/>
                    </var>
                   <var name="CLASS">
                       <string>macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver</string>
                    </var>
                 </struct>
              </var>
           </struct>
         </array>
       </data>  
</wddxPacket>
```

This uses an xpath expression `'var[@name="CLASS"]/string'` - which means any element `var` with a `name` attribute equal to `CLASS` with a subelement `string`. It will apply this to *any* instance that matches this. You may need a more specific xpath for your data. (e.g. `data/array/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var[@name="CFASTSTJ"]/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var[@name="CLASS"]/string` - that's probably overkill though :))

Note - I've fixed your XML - I'm assuming that's a typographic error, rather than broken source XML. If your source XML is broken, then you have bigger problems.

This outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
  <header/>
  <data>
    <array length="2">
      <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
        <var name="CFASTSTJ">
          <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
            <var name="alter">
              <boolean value="true" />
            </var>
            <var name="CLASS">
              <string>NoDatabase</string>
            </var>
          </struct>
        </var>
      </struct>
    </array>
  </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

Comment: Thank you Sobrique. what you have done is working fine but I want these changes should reflect in the same file  - neo-datasource instead of printing xml contents in output console.

Comment: I have given you a tool and an approach that will fix your problem.  If you are having difficulties with how to open, read and write files, then I would suggest that is a separate question.

Comment: I am not prepared to do that. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

This program uses the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module to process your data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( keep_spaces => 1 );
$twig->parsefile('neo-datasource.xml');

my ($class_string) = $twig->findnodes('//var[@name="CLASS"]/string');
$class_string->set_text('NoDatabase');

print $twig->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wddxPacket version="1.0">
  <header/>
  <data>
    <array length="2">
      <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
        <var name="CFASTSTJ">
          <struct type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap">
            <var name="alter">
              <boolean value="true"/>
            </var>
            <var name="CLASS">
              <string>NoDatabase</string>
            </var>
          </struct>
        </var>
      </struct>
    </array>
  </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

Comment: That is a different question to the one you asked. Asking it separately would be the appropriate course of action.

Comment: I wish these changes should reflect in the same xml file - neo-datasource instead of printing xml contents in output console. Could you please show me they way to do it.?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912884/how-to-modify-the-xml-value-that-should-reflect-in-the-same-xml-file-using-perl