# How to modify the xml value that should reflect in the same xml file using perl?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

Here is the perl script I have written to modify the particular value from the xml file — `neo-datasource.xml`.

I can print the modified xml contents in the output console using `->toString`, but I wish to have these changes to be reflected in the same xml file called `neo-datasource.xml` instead of printing it in console.

Could you please share your ideas?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;


my $twig = XML::Twig->new( keep_spaces => 1 );

$twig->parsefile('C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\dbautomate\neo-datasource.xml');

my ($class_string) = $twig->findnodes('//var[@name="d1new1d1"]/struct[@type="coldfusion.server.ConfigMap"]/var[@name="password"]/string');
$class_string->set_text('NoDatabase');


print $twig->toString;
```

Comment: Copy and paste of code supplied by a different user in a different question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30893035/2566198

Answer (score 1):

You're very nearly there — you just need to open the file for writing and print to it (not to STDOUT), something like:

```
open(my $fh, '>', 'C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\dbautomate\neo-datasource .xml')
    or die "Cannot open XML file for writing\n";
$fh->print($twig->toString);
```